# I want to motorize the big 10" wheels on the 4 wheel cart

Tags: electric-vehicles

[image]The ideal setup would be to have in-wheel drives  in one or both wheels; a transaxle drive would get in the way of the user. The weight of the cart is 75lbs and the machine it carries weighs 176lbs.
The delivery terrain is over ground with up to 30 degree inclines, as well as slopes to the left or right.
The big wheels are non-swivel and the smaller front wheels swivel.The cart can be pushed in either direction with handles that can be inserted into the top platform (which is removable by design) at either front or rear.But when going over uneven ground the big wheels should be in the front, leading the way.
The fact that the top of the cart is removable makes it impossible to wire hand controls to the handle, which is another obstacle.
The cart should travel at walking speed, and be able to be assisted. And it should be maneuverable when the motor is not engaged.
Please advise as to what I need.

Comment: Didn't someone already ask this a while back? For a project about motorized pull carts to help elderly bottle collectors or something like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One Wheel Drive utility wagon](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36530/one-wheel-drive-utility-wagon)

Comment: Show us some photos of the existing cart.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Like most, you need power.

Comment: I am looking for the best way to motorize this cart without spending more than $500-1,000. I am not an engineer. Just looking for suggestions. Perhaps a transaxle midway across the two bottom legs of cart with a powered wheel centered on transaxle.